# Компиляция libdeflate

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скомпилировать gzip из проекта [libdeflate](https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate)
Как это сделал автор программы.

Для компиляции использую MSYS2.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать gzip на основе libdeflate ?

Comment: Да, как я понимаю, это можно сделать. так сделал автор проекта https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate/releases. Я сделал небольшие изменения для улучшения сжатия, а как компилировать не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно изучите файл `Makefile` там посмотрите опции  `BUILD_GZIP_PROGRAM` `BUILD_PROGRAMS`

Comment: можно исправить сам файл,  а можно запустить `make BUILD_GZIP_PROGRAM=yes` с этой опцией.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас выдает ошибку

Comment: $ make BUILD_GZIP_PROGRAM=yes
gcc -o gzip  -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu99 -I. -D_ANSI_SOURCE tools/gzip.c libdeflate.a
C:/MSYS2/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:161: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «gzip»
make: *** [gzip] Ошибка 1

Comment: Ошибка говорит , что вместо `main` используется `WinMain` или `wmain`,  В mingw обычно используется `main`. Где то идет переопределение.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: найти в проекте переопределение `#define main wmain` и выключить его

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39806/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-lorents).