# Ошибка при компиляции libdeflate

Tags: c, gcc

Добрый день! При компиляции [libdeflate](https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate) выдает ошибку:

```
  CCLD     gzip
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:166: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «gzip»
make: *** [gzip] Ошибка 1
```

Для компиляции использую MSYS2. Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь собирать библиотеку, а компилятор собирает исполняемый файл (.exe вместо .dll).

Покажите командную строку компилятора.

Comment: Как я понимаю, ошибка в WinMain. Как можно ее решить?

Comment: А [предыдущий ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523709/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-libdeflate) не устраивает !

Comment: добрый день! Предыдущий ответ устраивает, еще раз благодарю Вас за ответ. Дело в том, что автор проекта сильно переписал его, и возникла такая же ошибка. Как я понимаю ошибка здесь https://github.com/ebiggers/libdeflate/blob/master/programs/prog_util.h#L59. Подскажите, как ее решить?

Comment: исправте в томже мести и будет работать

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Пробовал, выдает такую ошибку: CC programs/prog_util.o
programs/prog_util.c: In function 'xopen_for_read':

Comment: programs/prog_util.c:176:47: error: 'O_NOFOLLOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
strm->fd = topen(path, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY | O_NOFOLLOW);
programs/prog_util.c:176:47: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
programs/prog_util.c: In function 'xopen_for_write':
programs/prog_util.c:208:47: error: 'O_NOFOLLOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
strm->fd = topen(path, O_WRONLY | O_BINARY | O_NOFOLLOW |
Makefile:155: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «programs/prog_util.o»
make: *** [programs/prog_util.o] Ошибка 1